# How to make "diff" command including empty file when creating a patch file

Tags: python, linux, diff

In a linux system, suppose there 2 folders and 1 empty file: `fld1`,`fld1/__init__.py` and `fld2` (Here `__init__.py` is an empty file created by "touch" command).

Then I create a patch file with command `diff -urNp fld1 fld2 > tmp.patch`. No difference was found in `tmp.patch`.

If I remove "-N" option and only use `diff -urp fld1 fld2 > tmp.patch`, it can find the difference, but only shows: "Only in fld1: __init__.py" which is not a correct patch format.

To bypass this problem, I add one newline into `__init__.py` as a workaround. then "-urNp" works as expected.

But I still want to know: how can I use "diff" to create a correct patch file which also include empty files?

Comment: Off topic tip for writing more readable question/answer: use `\`code\`` to format filenames/commands, don’t use `**code**`, as it is used to emphasize words.

Comment: As in **not** using [`-N`](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Comparing-Directories)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `folder-structure is complex` so that `-urp` does not help.

Comment: Thanks to abccd, I have refined and supplement more. Also, thanks to dhke and Nurzhan, I supplemented the result without "-N".

Answer (score 0):

A nonexistent file and an empty file are represented in the same way in a patch file (`0,0`), so this is not possible. As you have done, you need to add some amount content to the file so that the patch has something to apply. An empty line or a comment is sufficient.